# Why do projective transformations preserve the degree of curves?

Tags: proof-explanation, curves, transformation, projective-geometry

While doing some reading on projective geometry, I found the following proposition and proof about projective transformations [here](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/%7Efranz/ag05/ag-07.pdf).

> Proposition $7.2.4$. Projective transformations preserve the degree of curves.
>
> Proof. Projective transformations map a monomial $X^i Y^i Z^k$ of degree $m=i+$ $j+k$ either to $0$ or to another homogeneous polynomial of degree $m$. If $f(X, Y, Z)$ is transformed by some transformation $T$ into the zero polynomial, then the inverse transformation maps the zero polynomial into $f$, which is nonsense.

I really don't understand how this proof is working. Isn't the very first sentence assuming the proposition is true already? And how is the inverse map "nonsense?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the author is pointing out boils down to the fact that when a projective transformation given by the matrix $A$ acts on the coordinates, it does so as follows:
\begin{align*}
[X:Y:Z] &= [U:V:W]A^{-1}\\
&= [U:V:W]\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= [a_{11}U+ a_{12}V+ a_{13}W: a_{21}U+ a_{22}V+ a_{23}W: a_{31}U+ a_{32}V+ a_{33}W]
\end{align*}
In particular, it takes each monomial $X^iY^jZ^k$ to the polynomial
\begin{align*}
X^iY^jZ^k &= (a_{11}U+ a_{12}V+ a_{13}W)^i(a_{21}U+ a_{22}V+ a_{23}W)^j(a_{31}U+ a_{32}V+ a_{33}W)^k
\end{align*}
which will also be a homogeneous polynomial of multidegree $m=i+j+k$ on formal variables $U, V, W$ (the degree zero reflects that a term could be mapped to a constant). To see this, use the [trinomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_expansion) and let the algebraic dust settle.

The last bit handles the case where each monomial is mapped to a constant which must be zero since we are dealing with homogeneous polynomials. If $f$ is our original polynomial that is transformed into $A(f)$ by $A$ then the above description of the action on the coordinates tells us that $A^{-1}(A(f))$ will be the zero polynomial. Nonetheless, $A^{-1}(A(f))=f$ and we assumed $f$ was non-zero implicitly.

Let me know if it would be helpful to expand on this answer or if this level of detail is sufficient.